# C# - Clamping an angle vs using modulo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the difference between clamping an angle like in the following code

```
do
 {
   if(angle < -360)
   {
     angle += 360;
   }
   if(angle > 360)
   {
     angle -= 360;
   }
 }while(angle < -360 || angle > 360);
```

... and using the modulo arithmetics;

```
angle = angle % 360;
```

... and if this is relevant for the Unity game engine.

Comment: `%` is a reminder operator. It divides your `angel` with `360` and returns the reminder. It is not the same as adding or subtracting `360`.

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." Come on people, it's not that hard.

Comment: The only difference I see is that this algorithm can result in the value 360 or -360, where modulo would return 0.

Comment: Thank you i forgot that the reminder is only positive !

Comment: The remainder is *not* only positive. Remainder obeys the rule that  `x % y == x - (x / y) * y`  That can give a negative remainder; do you see how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `angle` is an integer, the difference is that your clamp code allows angles of exactly `-360` or `+360` degrees. Modulo would reduce that to zero.

The comments speak of a difference in handling negative values. Those comments are wrong. Both approaches would leave `-10` as `-10`.

If `angle` isn't an integer type though, if it's `double` for instance, the `%` operator may give different results than repeated addition or subtraction, due to repeated addition or subtraction introducing rounding problems. In that case, the `%` operator would be a better match. You'd need excessively large angles for this to become a problem though, and with those excessively large angles, you don't have enough precision to represent angles accurately anyway.

Comment: Also, `3601` will be looped 10 times until it reaches `1`, but `3601 % 360` will return `1` in a single operation.

Comment: @SimpleVar True, but that's the "how", not the "what", and I think this question is focused on the "what".